# Microsoft Power Automate shorten length of an unknown string

Tags: arrays, string, power-automate

I want to shorten the length of a string to 40 Elements. I did try it with length(), last(), first()... but in order to convert it into an array I need to know the content of the string. The String I want to shorten could have any value.

Would be cool if you can share similiar problems or have a solution.

I tried to convert the string into an Array, with the split() function but I dont know the 40th Element.

By using the length function I could find out the length of the String I want to shorten.
Maybe there is something to delete the last few Elements of the string but I dont know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
substring(variables('String'),0,39)
```

This should solve your problem